# Rsyslog: Difference between logging to a UNIX domain socket or an INET socket (UDP)

Tags: logging, syslog, rsyslog

I am observing the following behaviour when logging to syslog from an external application: if I send a well-formed syslog message to a UDP socket, rsyslog correctly parses it, however if the very same message is sent to a UNIX domain socket (/dev/log), it is not parsed at all (rsyslog basically assumes, that everything, that he received, is a message, so no timestamp, no anything).

The message in question is

```
<142>1 2010-12-29T11:11:11Z foo bar 123 baz - A Message
```

which is parsed as

```
Dec 29 11:11:11 foo bar[123] A Message
```

unless it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should send the message without the hostname (foo) and in rfc3164 format (not rfc5424 as the above) to get it parsed.

Answer (score 0):

When parsing messages rsyslog does its best to make sense of it.

For a message received from an Unix socket, rsyslog accepts RFC 3164-like messages, using these fields: `pri`, `timestamp`, `tag`, and `content`.

It accepts various message formats, like :

- `just a message`
- `<pri>message`
- `<pri>tag: msg`

About the message timestamps:

1. They must be RFC3164 formatted.
2. Since the [`SysSock.IgnoreTimestamp`](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/imuxsock.html) option is enabled by default, your timestamps will be ignored until you disable this option.

The `hostname` field cannot be overridden. rsyslog will always get it from its configuration.